# Why does 52.0 as a float when cast as an int become 51?

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point

I have the following bit of code in Objective-C to turn an amount of seconds (int) into a date string of form "x hours y minutes z seconds". For 8812 seconds it should return 2 hours 26 minutes 52 seconds, but it's returning 2 hours 26 minutes 51 seconds.

This is the line that's troublesome:

```
float timeInSeconds = (60 * ((((seconds / 3600.0) - (seconds / 3600)) * 60.0) - (int)(((seconds / 3600.0) - (seconds / 3600)) * 60.0)));
```

This results in 52.0 if I `NSLog` it. However if I do:

```
int timeInSeconds = (int)(60 * ((((seconds / 3600.0) - (seconds / 3600)) * 60.0) - (int)(((seconds / 3600.0) - (seconds / 3600)) * 60.0)));
```

I get 51 when I `NSLog` it. Why is that exactly?

Comment: It wasn't actually 52.0 - it was 51.99999999 (or some such) and got truncated. Classical problem of floating point math.

Comment: How would I best deal with that then?

Comment: Use a call to roundf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code converts a time interval to hours/minutes/seconds
without using floating point numbers, and therefore without rounding problems
or precision loss:

```
int numberOfSeconds = 8812; // Your value as an example

int tmp = numberOfSeconds; 
int seconds = tmp % 60;
tmp /= 60;
int minutes = tmp % 60;
tmp /= 60;
int hours = tmp;

NSLog(@"%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
// Output: 2:26:52
```